# Редактура текста

Tags: стилистика

Редактирую текст. Смысл в том, что существуют две копии свидетельства о регистрации недвижимого имущества, в которых на планах приусадебного участка линии границ не совпадают. С первой частью все нормально, но как переделать вторую часть? Во второй части название документа оторвано. Мне кажется, что вторая часть должна начинаться с названия документа. В голову уже ничего не лезет.

**(1часть**)**В копии свидетельства о регистрации прав на недвижимое имущество N 0312315,  от 29 06 2000 г на плане приусадебного участка, принадлежащего  ХХХ,  3-4 линии углов границ геометрических фигур  не совпадают**  с 1, 1-7, и 7-6 линиями  углов  границ геометрических фигур на плане приусадебного участка, представленного  в копии свидетельства о регистрации прав на недвижимое имущество N792632,  от 19 10 2001 и принадлежащего ХХХ ...

Comment: *3-4 линиями углов границ...* - это тремя-четырьмя линиями? Падеж непонятен.

Comment: Галина, Людмила уже исправила, у меня ошибка. Сейчас исправлю.

Comment: Дополняю свой ответ, не подглядывая в предложенное Люсей.

Comment: Сделала попытку новой редактуры - ввела понятие "луч" (вместо "контур").

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что знание русского языка в  специфике документооборота межевания могут помочь только землемеру.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Серж, раз документы имеют разночтения, они уже не могут называться и/или считаться копиями.

Вы редактируете детектив? Это довольно частый сюжетный ход...

В одном романе: под документом стоит подпись, в которой нет сомнений и за которую (собственно, за легитимизацию каждого слова документа) подписавшему сейчас снесут голову...

Суть трюка была в том, что тончайшей бумагой с клеевым слоем была загорожена шапка документа - название с номером и адресат. Понятно, что поверх наклеенного "правильным" шрифтом напечатано нужное... преступнику. Но убивающее подписанта.

Не дай бог, Вы отредактируете криминал...

Берёте за грудки составителя свидетельства о регистрации и заявляете, что часть документа далеко-отнюдь-вовсе не документ.

---

Если же я неправильно поняла проблему и у Вас на руках несомненная копия, просто "накладываете" одно на другое, восстанавливая недостающее.

---

Дополнение после прочтения комментариев.

> В копии свидетельства о регистрации прав на недвижимое имущество №
>   0312315 от 29.06.2000 г. на плане приусадебного участка,
>   принадлежащего ХХХ, 3—4 линии углов границ геометрических фигур не
>   совпадают с 1, 1—7 и 7—6 линиями углов границ геометрических фигур на
>   плане приусадебного участка, представленного в копии свидетельства о
>   регистрации прав на недвижимое имущество № 792632 от 19.10.2001 г. и
>   принадлежащего ХХХ...

Это чисто формальная правка, корректура, а не редактура.

Как редактора меня смутили непонятные мне

а) "линии углов границ геометрических фигур" - какая у угла линия? зачем нам углы, когда есть слово "фигура", м?

> У́гол — геометрическая фигура, образованная двумя лучами (сторонами
>   угла), выходящими из одной точки (которая называется вершиной угла).

б) "не совпадают с 1, 1—7 и 7—6 линиями" - если с первой, то зачем повторять "с первой по седьмую"? почему в "7—6" вначале семь, а потом шесть?

Если Вам всё понятно в непонятом мною пункте б), то остаётся дважды убрать слово "угол" из пункта а):

> В копии свидетельства о регистрации прав на недвижимое имущество №
>   0312315 от 29.06.2000 г. на плане приусадебного участка,
>   принадлежащего ХХХ, 3—4 линии границ геометрических фигур не
>   совпадают с 1, 1—7 и 7—6 линиями границ геометрических фигур на
>   плане приусадебного участка, представленного в копии свидетельства о
>   регистрации прав на недвижимое имущество № 792632 от 19.10.2001 г. и
>   принадлежащего ХХХ...

Итого. Работать надо с "линиями углов границ геометрических фигур".

Может быть,

*углы граничащих геометрических фигур?*

То есть углы-то как раз сохраняем, но убираем принадлежащие им загадочные линии...

---

Дополнение-2. Обновлённая редактура.

> В копии свидетельства о регистрации прав на недвижимое имущество №
>   0312315 от 29.06.2000 г. на плане приусадебного участка,
>   принадлежащего ХХХ, 3—4 граничащие лучи углов геометрических фигур не
>   совпадают с 1, 1—7 и 7—6 граничащими лучами углов геометрических фигур на
>   плане приусадебного участка, представленного в копии свидетельства о
>   регистрации прав на недвижимое имущество № 792632 от 19.10.2001 г. и
>   принадлежащего ХХХ...

Comment: Галина, не сами документы имеют разночтения, а представленные в них данные.  Это заключение суда на армянском. Русский текст - перевод.

Comment: Серж, это ж одно и то же! Мы говорим о "разночтениях", когда два источника имеют хоть одну несовпадающую букву или знак. Разночтения в данных = разночтения в документах. Нельзя редактировать судебные бумаги - в историю можно влипнуть.

Comment: Нет, Галина, это два одинаковых документа, но принадлежащих разным лицам. Т. е. свидетельства на землю двух разных людей.

Comment: Я редактирую стилистику перевода.

Comment: Нет криминала - нет проблемы: списывайте и вписывайте недостающее из одного документа в другой.

Comment: Галина, списывать и вписывать ничего не надо. )) Я же говорю: это перевод, который надо грамотно передать на русский.

Comment: Дайте в дополнении к вопросу полный текст, требующий редактуры. Будет Вам по-русски.

Comment: Галина, со всем текстом все в порядке. Вот это часть никак не получается.

Comment: Вы пишете, что со второй частью что-то не получается, а жирным выделено *(1часть)В копии свидетельства...* Этот кусок редактировать?

Comment: Да, это чтобы было понятно, что эту часть трогать не надо. Может, вторую часть выделить?

Comment: @ Галина,спасибо, текст приобрел вид. По поводу цифр: ничего не могу сказать. Это геодезический текст.  Как было в оригинале, так и оставил.

Comment: И здесь вы правы: скорее граничащих углов.Но как впихнуть в текст?

Comment: Дословный перевод таков: ... граничные конторы углов геометрических фигур.

Comment: Не-а! ))) *Граничащие контуры углов геометрических фигур*! Но *контур угла* - уже не по-русски... М. б., *лучи* углов, как в математическом определении?

Comment: Спасибо! Все сделал так, как вы написали.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, всё нормально, по крайней мере понятно, только поправить "линиями" на "линии"(не совпадает что с чем).

Можно изменить. Но лучше ли это  будет?

В копии свидетельства о регистрации прав на недвижимое имущество N 0312315 от 29. 06. 2000 г на плане приусадебного участка, принадлежащего ХХХ, 3-4 лин**ии** углов границ геометрических фигур не совпадают с координатами границ на плане приусадебного участка, представленного в копии свидетельства о регистрации прав на недвижимое имущество N792632 от 19.10. 2001 и принадлежащего ХХХ (расхождение с линиями 1, 1-7, и 7-6).

Comment: Понимаете, это постановление суда на армянском, а русский текст представляет собой перевод. В обоих частях говорится о линях границ на плане приусадебного участка. Хотя мне ваш вариант понравился, но все же заключать в скобки не хочется цифры, Все-аки строго-научный стиль, да и в оригинале не так,

Comment: Ну и оставьте первый вариант, там всё верно,кроме первого  "линиями".

Comment: Да, но мне что-то не нравится, чувствуется шершавость.